# Node js - Global variables to be used in different files

Tags: node.js, global-variables, require

I have a main file called `index.js`. Here, I want to do some global stuff which can be used by different js file:

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const firebase = require('firebase');
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var app = require('express')();
const express = require('express')
const scheduler = require('node-schedule')
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const OneSignal = require('onesignal-node');    
const client = new OneSignal.Client('XXX', 'XXX');
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000 

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
 databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'XXX',
  projectId: 'XXX'
});
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);

 var database = firebase.firestore(); 

const constant = require('./Constant.js')
const tournamentDataAccessService = require('./TournamentDataAccessService.js')
const tournamentParticipationDataAccessService = 
require('./TournamentParticipationDataAccessService.js')

constant = new Constants()
```

My problem occurs in line     **constant = new Constants()**
Here we need to check the **Constants.js**

```
class Constants {
  

constructor() {
   console.log(database) // database is defined in index.js file
}
```

}

Compiler complains about **database;**. To be more precise, **database** can't be found. How can I access the **database** variable in the index.js? file? I could pass the variable as a parameter to the constructor of Constants.js but is there a different solution?

Comment: You import and export things shared between modules - don't use global variables.

Comment: Hello @jfriend00, can you show me an example, please?

Comment: This is the basics of the module system in nodejs.  There are thousands or articles on it on the web and there are probably thousands of questions/answers here on stackoverflow all about it.  Any intro tutorial or article on nodejs modules will show you examples.